# Select email that triggers script

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am working on a Outlook script that will automatically select an email, and download the attachments, from a specific sender.

Reports are generated on a database and emailed to a specified address.

The next step is to automatically download those reports to a specified folder. Currently if an email comes in from the specified sender the script downloads attachments from the currently selected email.

I need the script to run on the email that triggers the script.

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachments(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
 
    'Get the path to the target folder
    strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    On Error Resume Next
 
    'Instantiate an Outlook Application Object
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 
    'Get the collection of selected objects
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    'Set the Attachment folder
    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"
 
    'Check each selected item for attachements. If attachments exist, save them
    'to the strFOlderPath folder and strip them from the item.
    For Each objMsg In objSelection
 
    'This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    'If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    'Get the Attachments collection of the item
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFile = ""
   
    If lngCount > 0 Then
   
        'A count down loop needs to be used for removing items
        'from a collection. Otherwise the loop counter gets
        'confused and only every other item is removed
       
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
       
            'Save attachment before deleting from item.
            'Get the file name
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
           
            'Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
           
            'Save the attachment as a file
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
           
            'Delete the attachment
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete
           
            'write the save as path to a string to add to the
            'message check from html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFile = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If
           
            'use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles
           
        Next i
       
        'Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        'Checks for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The File(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
    Next
 
Exit Sub:
 
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: **Caution**: If strFolderpath does not exist, the error when saving will be bypassed.
The attachments will be **unrecoverably** deleted without being saved. This is due to improper use of `On Error Resume Next`. "There are specific occasions when this is useful. Most of the time you should avoid using it." https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes and this code does the intended purpose.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String


'Get the path to the target folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next

'Instantiate an Outlook Application Object
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Set the Attachment folder
strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"

'Check each selected item for attachements. If attachments exist, save them
'to the strFOlderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objAttachments In Item.Attachments

    'This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    'If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    'Get the Attachments collection of the item
    Set objAttachments = Item.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFile = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        'A count down loop needs to be used for removing items
        'from a collection. Otherwise the loop counter gets
        'confused and only every other item is removed

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            'Save attachment before deleting from item.
            'Get the file name
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            'Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            'Save the attachment as a file
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            'Delete the attachment
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the
            'message check from html and use html tags in link
            If Item.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFile = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        'Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        'Checks for HTML body
        If Item.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
             Item.Body = vbCrLf & "The File(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & Item.Body
         Else
            Item.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & Item.HTMLBody
        End If
        Item.Save
    End If
Next objAttachments

Exit Sub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: **Caution**: If strFolderpath does not exist, the error when saving will be bypassed.
The attachments will be **unrecoverably** deleted without being saved. This is due to improper use of `On Error Resume Next`. "There are specific occasions when this is useful. Most of the time you should avoid using it." https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next

Answer (score 0):

To apply code to the item, do not select anything.

Instead use `Item` passed in `(Item As MailItem)`.

---

In the question and the answer posted by the OP, if `strFolderpath` does not exist, the error when saving will be bypassed.
The attachments will be **unrecoverably** deleted without being saved.

This is due to improper use of `On Error Resume Next`.
"There are specific occasions when this is useful. Most of the time you should avoid using it."
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub test()
SaveAttachments ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAttachments(Item As MailItem)

'Check the Item passed in (Item As MailItem) for attachments.
'
'If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderpath folder and
' strip them from the item.

Dim objAttachment As Attachment
Dim objAttachments As Attachments

Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long

Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String

Dim strDeletedFiles As String

'Get the path to the target folder
strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
Debug.Print strFolderpath

'Set the Attachment folder
strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"
Debug.Print strFolderpath

'Get the Attachments collection of the item
Set objAttachments = Item.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count

'A count down loop for removing items, through move or delete, from a collection.
'Otherwise only every other item is removed.
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    'Save attachment before deleting from item.
    'Get the file name
    strFile = objAttachments(i).fileName
    Debug.Print strFile
            
    'Combine the path to the folder with file name.
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
    Debug.Print strFile
    
    'Save the attachment as a file
    'If strFolderpath does not exist there will be an error.
    'This is good.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    
    'Delete the attachment
    ' Uncomment after verifying attachments are being saved
    'objAttachments.Item(i).Delete
            
    'Write the save as path to a string to add to the message
    'Check from html and use html tags in link
    If Item.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
    Else
        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
          strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
    End If
            
Next

'Add the filename string to the message body and save it
'Check for HTML body
If Item.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
    Item.body = vbCrLf & "The File(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & Item.body
Else
    Item.HtmlBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & Item.HtmlBody
End If

Item.Display    'Item.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass the mailitem that triggers the script as a parameter.

If, for example, you pass Item then process Item.

```
Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As MailItem)
    MsgBox "Mail message arrived: " & Item.Subject
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I made that change but the script is failing to select the correct email. I think this line is causing the error.

   

     'Get the collection of selected objects
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection